# Open a file in a print window by getting the file from the file url specified

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to implement a print option in my application using `jQuery`. I will have the `url of the file` to be printed as the `src` attribute of an `<a> tag`. All I am trying to do is to get the file from the url specified and open it in the print window from where user can print it. The code i use is as follows:

```
<a id="print-5569" href="http://www.ibiblio.org/ebooks/Baum/Santa_Claus.pdf "><i class="fa fa-download"></i></a>
```

I tried many solutions found online, but noting worked for me. One of the sample I tried is the one below:
https://www.sitepoint.com/load-pdf-iframe-call-print/

While I search online, i find plugins for this. But i dont want to add a plugin just for this. Is there any solution for this.

Comment: printing PDF will probably not work in all bowsers, and depends on the default Viewer and so on. If it should be supported on all browser you will need an different solution. May be somthing like https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/ can help.

Comment: "just for this" - this is a complex functionality, use a plugin.

Comment: @Samuil Petrov any suggestion?

Comment: A relatively straight-forward solution imo would be to use this: https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/ (see the examples) to render the extracted pdf in a div that has asigned css styles to be visible only on @media print {} and to be fixed with 100% width and height; and then invoke window.print() method.

Comment: I tried implementing using the plugins, but I have a new issue. My pdfs would  be stored in a different domain and these plugins do not support cross origin files to be printed. Can you suggest me a plugin that supports cross origin file printing.

Answer (score 3):

To directly print the file from the same page

**Step 1: Download the file as Blob**

```js
// Using fetch
const response = await fetch("http://www.ibiblio.org/ebooks/Baum/Santa_Claus.pdf");
const blob = await response.blob();
```

```js
// Using axios
const response = await axios.get("http://www.ibiblio.org/ebooks/Baum/Santa_Claus.pdf",
  { responseType: "blob" }
);
const blob = response.data;
```

**Step 2: Create iframe and open the print prompt**

```js
const fileUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

let iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
document.body.appendChild(iframe);

iframe.style.display = "none";
iframe.src = fileUrl;
iframe.onload = function () {
  iframe.focus();
  iframe.contentWindow.print();
};
```

Answer (score -1):

If the pdf is stored on the same domain, you can do this:

```
document.getElementById('print-5569').addEventListener('click', () => {
    var w = window.open('http://www.ibiblio.org/ebooks/Baum/Santa_Claus.pdf');
    w.print();
});
```

Otherwise, you can pair this method with a simple pdf proxy type thing running on the same domain, like google drive has. (ex. https://drive.google.com/viewerng/viewer?url=http://www.ibiblio.org/ebooks/Baum/Santa_Claus.pdf)

Comment: Won't work in FF. First you are not waiting for the window as loaded, so at the time you call it, you'll just print an `about:blank` page. Then, even if waiting for the page has loaded, the browser has some pdf reader included, which will block the calls to `print`. And It won't work either in browsers that don't have a pdf reader plugin included.